# Setting an Integer from a if-then statement

Tags: java

I am trying to get it so if i put a piece of code such as

```
if ((variable1 - variable2) < 0)
        int variable5 = (variable3 + variable4);
```

but this does not seem to work for me. So i was wondering if anyone had a solution?

Comment: Can you explain - *doesn't work*?

Comment: You have to add some more explanation. What is variable,variable1...and what are there types and values?

Comment: does your `variable5` already exist? if so you can't declare it inside your `if` . you can do `variable5 = (variable3 + variable4);`

Comment: what is the value of variable 1 and variable

Comment: You have no brackets in your if statement, so variable 5 goes out of scope immediately.

Comment: @kiwiron no it doesn't

Comment: @xgeorgekx I think it does, although it has nothing to do with the lack of brackets.

Comment: By doesn't work i mean i get a Syntax Error

Comment: @NatzoHD: Please include the *exact* error in your question. Always, always, always give details about the way in which something isn't working. If there's an error message (or an exception), always copy and paste it into the question.

Comment: @kiwiron well in theory it doesn't. He has a single line inside the `if` so the variable is within the `if`'s scope. The problem is when he adds more lines, he needs brackets then yeah

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to *declare* a variable as the only statement in an `if` statement body. That's not allowed, as it would be pointless - the variable would be out of scope immediately afterwards. Either you should declare the variable first:

```
int variable5 = 0; // Or whatever value you want otherwise
if (variable1 - variabl < 0)
    variable5 = variable3 + variable4;
```

Or if you only need the variable within the body of the `if` statement, you'll need more statements:

```
if (variable1 - variabl < 0) {
    int variable5 = variable3 + variable4;
    // Use variable5
}
```

I would strongly encourage you to *always* use braces with `if` statements (and loops etc).

Comment: +1 for giving both possible uses, as opposed to just assuming the use.

Comment: Yeah i still have a few minutes to accept it. But thanks im currently doing work experience and teaching my self java for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a local variable if you only use 1 statement as the body of `if`.

Try this:

```
int variable5 = 0; // Default value
if (variable1 - variable < 0)
    variable5 = variable3 + variable4;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining your integer inside the if and it is a single line if block, so therefore the variable is just declared and then removed since it runs out of scope -

```
if ((variable1 - variable) < 0)
     int variable5 = (variable3 + variable4);
```

Declare it outside -

```
int variable5 = 0;
if ((variable1 - variable) < 0)
     variable5 = (variable3 + variable4);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you create a new variable when "if condition" returns true.
So as soon as the "block of code of if condition" ends, your block variable "variable5" is destroyed. And so you cannot use it.

Either declare it before your if-condition block and assign it a value in the block
OR if you want it to declare within the block of if-condition, Use it inside that block only!